# Detect if a python pdb process is in break or waiting state

Tags: python-3.x, unix, process, pdb

In Unix OS, is it possible to detect if a python program running in pdb, is in "break" or "waiting" state, given the process ID?

I would like to detect that from outside the python program itself, i.e. a secondary program/process monitoring it.

I tried tailing the stdout of the process, and checking for (pdb).
Also tried detecting if process is in sleep state (S+), but this could happen for other reasons.

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It would help if you provided more context such as why you're trying to do this.

Comment: it is in fact an XY Problem. Was trying to monitor a specific process, and send alerts on when it would break. A quick solution I had in mind at the start was to check if it is in pdb, then it would be in break state. Realized this wouldn't work, so currently implementing alerts based on logs rather than the process state.